# Partially colored Arabic word in HTML

Tags: html, arabic

I don't speak Arabic, but I need specific support for Arabic on our web. I need parts of Arabic words to be in a `<span>` with a different style than the rest of word. When I type two characters `ش` and `س`, they are composed into word `شس`, but when I use HTML markup

```
<span>ش</span>س
```

these letters are not concatenated right in the output.

[image]

In the picture, desired output is on second line, actual output is on first line.

***EDIT:*** It works on Firefox, but does not work in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Looks fine here: http://jsbin.com/edimiq/2

Comment: your spans have display set to inline, dont they?

Comment: Spans are inline. Now I see, that it works in Firefox, but does not work in Chrome/Safari on my Mac :(

Comment: Just FYI, I'm finding the same thing in XAML. Using two zwj's doesn't help in some situations, like `بد&#x200d;<Span Foreground="Red">&#x200d;ه</Span>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Insert a zero-width joiner (e.g. using the entity reference `&zwj;`) at the end of the `span` element content: `<span>ش&zwj;</span>س`.

More generally, the zero-width joiners at the start and end of each `span` element as well as (just to be more sure) before and after each `span` element, in situations where the text should have cursive (joining) behavior and `span` may break it.

The issue is discussed and illustrated on the [Bidirectional text](http://www.user.uni-hannover.de/nhtcapri/bidirectional-text.html) page by Andreas Prilop.

**Update:** Unfortunately, it seems that even `&zwj;` does not help on current versions of WebKit browsers. They seem to treat HTML markup as breaking joining behavior, no matter what.

**Update 2:** As described in @NasserAl-Wohaibi’s comment, the new problem can be solved by using `&zwj;` twice. However, in current Safari (5.1.7) for Windows, it does not help; in fact, it displays even `ش&zwj;س` wrong whereas without the joiner, it shows `شس` correctly.

Comment: +1, a nice one. @Ondra, this seems as a more eligible candidate for the *accepted answer*, mind you.

Comment: Wow...learn something new every day. It looked like some kind of ligature issue to me, so I just assumed there was no solution.

Comment: as for your update , try adding **two** `&zwj;`, before the letter in the inner span AND after the word in outer span, works fine with me in chrome23. e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noonon/esz4S/2/)

Comment: When the text is in italics (`font-style: italic`), this does not work anymore. Look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjDFw/1/). Easy solution, get rid off the italics :S

Answer (score 4):

As [Jukka K. Korpela](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156606/1085495) indicated, This is mostly a bug in most **WebKit-based browsers**(chrome, safari, etc).

A simple hack other than the TAMDEED char or getting contextual forms for Arabic letters would be to put the **zero-width-joiner** (`&zwj;` or `&#x200d;`) before/after the letter you want to be treated as single Arabic [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_ligature) - two chars making up another one. e.g.

```
<p>عرب&#x200d;<span style="color: Red;">&#x200d;ي</span></p>
```

demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noonon/esz4S/2/)
see also the webkit [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6148) report.

Comment: Chrome 76 has a new layout engine LayoutNG  which resolves this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/06/layoutNG

Comment: iOS still uses webkit, so it's still a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a [reported bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6148), thus presumably affects all WebKit-based browsers.

Comment: Wow, a bug from 2005. Before Chrome even existed!

Comment: This is resolved in Chrome 76 which is in late beta now. Finally.