# change jquery ui combobox font

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

how to change the font inside jquery ui combobox and the dropdown list
my code is:

```
.ui-autocomplete-input {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0.3em;
                font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            }
            .ui-autocomplete 
            {
                font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
                max-height: 200px;
                overflow-y: auto;
                /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
                overflow-x: hidden;
                /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */
                z-index:1000;
            }
```

but nothing change I don't know where is the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
     font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 }
```

Comment: it worked but the same error from is thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689144/arabic-characters-are-displayed-separately-in-google-chrome
if you can help me as you know much about jquery ui will be grate

Comment: Try: .ui-widget {font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work :S thank you for your help and your try :D

Answer (score 1):

It would have been overridden by some other CSS. You can theme your jQuery UI using [this](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your jQuery UI look, you should use the tool supplied by the developers - [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). Even if you find a way to set the font as you'd like, chances are you aren't fully aware of the theme settings and how  they evaluate, meaning sometimes you might get the correct behaviour, other times you won't.

That being said, if you add `!important` to the end of a CSS setting it overrides other styles:

```
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
```

But you should probably not do this.