# How to determine character in textnode that was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can set up an event listener to tell me when a mouse click occurred at some place in an HTML document.  But if the click occurred on some text, I need to know which character in the text the click occurred over.  Is there a way to do this?

I can think of some really obnoxious solutions.  For instance, for every single character in the document I could wrap it in a separate element with its own event.  Or, since I can tell which textnode the click occurred in, I could perform some kind of calculation (basically almost like simulating rendering of the text) perhaps using clientWidth, to determine which character the click occurred in.

Surely there must be something easier?

Comment: check the position of the caret http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/

Comment: You *should* be able to create a text node for each character and then have the node referenced by the related event. However, only one browser that I know of implemented that model and it now conforms to the more prevalent model of only allowing elements to be event targets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once the mouse event is captured, split the text in the element into two separate spans.  Look at the offset of each span to determine which the event occurred in.  Now split that span in two and compare again.  Repeat until you have a span that has a single character whose coordinates contain the coordinates of the mouse click.  Since this is essentially a binary search this whole process will be fairly quick, and the total number of span low compared to the alternative.  Once the character has been found, the spans can be dissolved and all the text returned to the original element.

Answer (score 3):

You do, unfortunately, have to wrap every character in an element, but you do not have to attach an event listener to each one. When the `click` event is fired on the element, it is bubbled up to its parents. You can then retrieve the element that was actually clicked by using the `target` property of the event.

Say we've got some text in an element named `textElement`. It contains a `span` for each character. If we wanted to be able to click on characters to delete them, we could use this code:

```
textElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    textElement.removeChild(e.target);
}, false);
```

**[Try it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/HLzU4/)**

Comment: hmm, okay.  i guess my main concern with this approach is memory, i imagine it is going to take some multiple of the original document size to wrap every character in a separate text element, maybe 10x? 20x?  and, possibly this might cause performance issues although maybe this is less likely.

Comment: Those are valid concerns. Unfortunately, I don't know what impact this approach has on those.

Comment: Quick test of 10,000 characters in Firefox 14 shows a memory increase of about 500k for the initial page, and another 3.5MB to wrap everything in spans, with about 2 seconds to do the wrapping.  Freshly run copy shows around 170 bytes of RAM for each character.

Comment: Its problematic with some languages like arabic, burmese, or khmer. Chars are not connected properly when placed into different spans. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html

Comment: Also, in some browsers, italic font-styles sometimes overflow outside of the spans and get cut off.  overflow: visible does nothing...

Answer (score 3):

This is my effort to implement what Michael wrote in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771033/9486175):

```
function hitCharBinSearch(mClientX, inmostHitEl) {

    const originalInmost = inmostHitEl
    const bareText = inmostHitEl.firstChild.textContent
    var textNode = inmostHitEl.firstChild
    var textLenghtBeforeHit = 0
    do {
        let textNodeR = textNode.splitText(textNode.length / 2)
        let textNodeL = textNode

        let spanL = document.createElement('span')
        spanL.appendChild(textNodeL)
        let spanR = document.createElement('span')
        spanR.appendChild(textNodeR)

        inmostHitEl.appendChild(spanL)
        inmostHitEl.appendChild(spanR)

        if (mClientX >= spanR.getBoundingClientRect().left) {
            textNode = textNodeR
            inmostHitEl = spanR
            textLenghtBeforeHit += textNodeL.length
        }
        else {
            textNode = textNodeL
            inmostHitEl = spanL
        }
    } while (textNode.length > 1)

    /* This is for proper caret simulation. Can be omitted */
    var rect = inmostHitEl.getBoundingClientRect()
    if (mClientX >= (rect.left + rect.width / 2)) 
        textLenghtBeforeHit++
    /*******************************************************/

    originalInmost.innerHTML = bareText
    return textLenghtBeforeHit
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly clever.  As long as you are okay with temporarily changing the DOM to do this, this is the best answer. Although this is based on another answer, Oleksa gets props for the implementation (although I had to change the vars to lets and correct spelling).

Answer (score 0):

Placing each character in a document model object is not as obnoxious as it sounds.  HTML parsing, DOM representation, and event handling is quite efficient in terms of memory and processing in modern browsers.  A similar mechanism is used at a low level to render the characters too.  To simulate what the browser does at that level takes much work.

- Most documents are constructed with variable width characters
- Wrapping can be justified or aligned in a number of ways
- There is not a one to one mapping between characters and bytes
- To be a truly internationalized and robust solution, surrogate pairs must be supported too <sup>1</sup>

This example is lightweight, loads quickly, and is portable across common browsers.  Its elegance is not immediately apparent, much reliability is gained by establishing a one to one correspondence between international characters and event listeners.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Character Click Demo</title>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
          var pre = "<div onclick='charClick(this, ";
          var inf = ")'>";
          var suf = "</div>"; 
          function charClick(el, i) {
              var p = el.parentNode.id;
              var s = "para '" + p + "' idx " + i + " click";
              ele = document.getElementById('result');
              ele.innerHTML = s; }
          function initCharClick(ids) {
              var el; var from; var length; var to; var cc;
              var idArray = ids.split(" ");
              var idQty = idArray.length;
              for (var j = 0; j < idQty; ++ j) {
                  el = document.getElementById(idArray[j]);
                  from = unescape(el.innerHTML);
                  length = from.length;
                  to = "";
                  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++ i) {
                      cc = from.charAt(i);
                      to = to + pre + i + inf + cc + suf; }
                  el.innerHTML = to; } }
      </script>
      <style>
          .characters div {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              display: inline }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body class='characters' onload='initCharClick("h1 p0 p2")'>
      <h1 id='h1'>Character Click Demo</h1>
      <p id='p0'>&#xE6;&#x20AC; &ndash; &#xFD7;&#xD8; &mdash;</p>
      <p id='p1'>Next  E para.</p>
      <p id='p2'>&copy; 2017</p>
      <hr>
      <p id='result'>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

---

[1] This simple example does not have handling for surrogate pairs, but such could be added in the body of the i loop.