# Get clicked letter from p tag

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to get the letter clicked in p tag using javascript. But instead of getting a single word, I am getting the whole tag.

```js
function myFunction() {
        var s = document.getSelection()
        var node = s.anchorNode
        console.log(node)
        var item = node.nodeValue.trim()
        alert(item)
    }
```

```css
p{
font-size:3rem;
font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="myFunction()">♂️♥️</p>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine character in textnode that was clicked on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752300/how-to-determine-character-in-textnode-that-was-clicked-on)

Comment: You can split it characters in to span and then add event listener on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the list of letters into individual elements, which would allow the event listener `target` to return the individual letter.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let letters = document.querySelector('.letters');
  letters.innerHTML = letters.innerText.split('').map(l => `<span>${l}</span>`).join('');
  document.querySelector('.letters').addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(e.target.innerText);
  })
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<p class='letters'>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
```

Comment: Why use `<i>` instead of `<span>`?

Comment: good question. brevity, I suppose. I changed to span b/c it makes more sense, thx

Answer (score 1):

You have a string within an element, the element is clickable and can have an event on it. However, to determine the exact character you are clicking on you will need to wrap the character in an element that can be identified as its own selector.

One way to do this would be to get the textContent of the element (***the characters***), ***split*** the string creating an ***array*** of each character. Then *iterate* over that ***array*** and create a `span` tag, add a class to it for click events, and place each characters value into each `span` tag. Then append each tag back into the element.

Then you can create an eventListener that listens for clicks on the class that was added.

```js
function getChar(e) {
  console.log(e.target.textContent)
}

function createClickables() {
  const str = document.querySelector('.info')
  const parts = str.textContent.split('')
  str.textContent = ''
  parts.forEach(char => {
    let span = document.createElement('SPAN')
    span.textContent = char
    span.classList.add('char')
    str.append(span)
  })
}

createClickables()

const chars = document.querySelectorAll('.char')
chars.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', getChar)
})
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.char {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="info">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>
```