# Why does adding formatting to Arabic/Persian text in TextBlock break combining characters in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, arabic, persian

In a given word, I want to show one or more Perso-Arabic letters with different formatting (e.g., different color, larger size, etc.). This breaks the combining characters though. In the 3 items below:
1) the word wrapped in a `<Span/>` and it displays correctly
2) The word's middle letter wrapped in a `<Span/>` and it displays correctly
3) The word's middle letter wrapped in a `<Span/>` with it's color changed to red - it **does not display correctly**

```
        <TextBlock xml:lang="fa-IR" Language="fa-IR" FontSize="60" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                <Span Foreground="Yellow">حال</Span>
                ح<Span>ا</Span>ل
                ح<Span Foreground="Red">ا</Span>ل
            </TextBlock.Inlines>
        </TextBlock>
```

The XAML I'm using is WP8 variant. Is there anyway around this issue to have formatting applied and not break combining characters?

Comment: Just as an additional note, this doesn't not happen with Latin letters, e.g. `hea<Span Foreground="Green">l</Span>th` works as expected.

Comment: If it's based on like SL xaml, it respects the linebreaks as spaces like it would in xml. Try putting the elements to be non-spaced on the same line. Although personally I'm not familiar with using SPAN in SL style xaml, more so instead opting for like <TextBlock><Run Text="blah" Foreground="Red"/><Run Text="blah" Foreground="Blue"/></TextBlock> instead. Worth a shot, and since I had no time to test, entered as comment instead of answer.

Comment: @ChrisW., everything on one line is exactly the same result. I've tried with Runs, Spans, everything in Runs/Spans, only formatted text in Runs/Spans, etc. Nothing works once formatting is set. For example `<Run Text="ح"/><Run Text="ا" Foreground="Red"/><Run Text="ل"/>` (all on one line or each run on a separate line) **does not work**. `<Run Text="ح"/><Run Text="ا"><Run Text="ل"/>` **does work** however - the only difference is that I removed `Foreground="Red"` from the middle `<Run/>`

Comment: Well that's interesting, I'll tinker with it later if I get some free time since now I'm curious.

Comment: Not an answer but, FWIW, this seems like a Silverlight specific issue. Your XAML seems to work fine with WPF but not in Silverlight (web) and WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid if there a complete solution, but as a workaround you can use 2 special Unicode characters. Use [`ARABIC TATWEEL` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0640/index.htm) after `ح` and use [`ZERO WIDTH JOINER` character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200d/index.htm) after `ا`.

In `HTML` you should try this:

```
ح&#1600;<strong>ا&#8205;</strong>ل
```

You can try it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro). For more info refer to Iranian national standards [`ISIRI 6219`](http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C_%DB%B6%DB%B2%DB%B1%DB%B9) and [`ISIRI 9147`](http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B2%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C_9147). You can also try asking question in [`Persian Computing Community`](http://persian-computing.org/).

Comment: Good links, but solutions like coding my own ZWJ, ZWNJ, etc are not really an option. You'll see similar solutions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886663/why-do-arabic-characters-behave-as-separate-characters-when-styling-single-arabi/, but having tried this, there is too much logic to consider in accounting for every scenario.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But seems no real solution exists. Another workaround would be creating an engine for rendering characters instead of WPF/SL. Can not examine how many coding it may need.