# Highlighting the word in arabic

Tags: html, arabic

I want to highlight the the arabic diacretics with  but it changes the form of the word,

```
ك<span style="color:blue">َ</span>تَبَ
```

and this turns into

```
كَ تَبَ
```

but it should be like this:

```
كَتَبَ
```

Is there's any way of doing this

Comment: You forgot to explain in what way the "form of the word" is changed and how you attempt to change it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do Arabic characters behave as separate characters when styling single Arabic character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886663/why-do-arabic-characters-behave-as-separate-characters-when-styling-single-arabi)

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html?rq=1 it might help

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069247/inserting-html-tag-in-the-middle-of-arabic-word-breaks-word-connection-cursive?rq=1

Comment: Is there supposed to be something inside of the span?

Comment: thanks, @jumpingcode you can see small charackter on </span>

Comment: This does not look like a duplicate of previous question (though it has some connections). This is about coloring a diacritic mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the question is different from [Partially colored Arabic word in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html), the basic answer is the same: use the ZERO WIDTH JOINER (ZWJ) character to request for cursive joining, which might not otherwise take place across element boundaries. Using ZWJ multiple times is the safest bet:

```
ك&zwj;<span style="color:blue">&zwj;َ&zwj;</span>&zwj;تَبَ
```

This seems to fix the issue in Chrome. In firefox, the problem does not seem to exist, but there is the problem that the diacritic is not colored. For some odd reason, the ZWJ code fixes this, too. On IE 11, the situation is the same but the ZWJ code does not fix the color issue.