# Arabic text in Ionic - Changing color of one letter changes the format

Tags: html, ionic-framework, arabic, text-formatting

When I change the color of one letter in Ionic in the `.html-data`, my word gets longer than normal (look at the picture). The normal output is Output 2.

[image]

Output 1: The word gets longer if I do it like this. It happens when I add that line to join the letters:

```
<button>
    <span style="font-size: 30px">مَـ<span style="color:red">ـرَ</span>جَ</span> 
</button>
```

Output 3: This happens when I don't add the lines to join them. They are not joining, but they have to be joined:

```
<button>
    <span style="font-size: 30px">مَ<span style="color:red">رَ</span>جَ</span>
</button>
```

What can I do to have the normal length of the word when I change the color of one letter?

Thanks you all for any help!

Comment: Try playing with [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing), something like `button span { letter-spacing: -1px; }`

Comment: Thanks! I tried but it doesnt effect the joined letters with the line

Comment: Can you post the html of 2?

Comment: <button>
    <span style="font-size: 30px">مَرَجَ</span>
</button>

Comment: thank you all ! i found the solution :))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html