# How to select part of a text using select method?

Tags: javascript

I want to select a part of a text with JavaScript. I want to specify the range based on length not using nodes. For instance: I have text "AB DDSD" and I want to select from 0-3. I cannot wrap it with an element like `span` because the Arabic letters do not concatenate.

The following example selects all text inside `foo` class but how to specify a range for it?

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(txt);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

I am open to using other methods instead of `select`. My goal is to color certain characters in `p` tag but cannot wrap it using any element. If I wrap only one character of `سس` then it turns into `س س`.

Answer (score 1):

The ligatures are in fact preserved:

```js
let t = document.getElementById('test');
t.innerHTML = `<span style="color: red">${t.textContent.slice(0,3)}</span>${t.textContent.slice(3)}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
 <body>
  <span id="test">مرحبا بالعالم</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

This may have to do with the the font and rendering of your browser, but here's how mine looks:

[image]

I don't think adding a zero-width space is the solution considering its [purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding `span` around the text creates a concatenation problem. In your example the text is returns as `مرح با بالعالم` instead of `مرحبا بالعالم`

Comment: I am using Safari that's why it does not concatenate for me. Maybe you are using Chrome or Firefox. The zero-width also does not give a preferred result.

Comment: I hear your pain, Maihan, it seems that this is still in [draft state](https://www.w3.org/TR/alreq/)

Comment: I have filed a bug at Safari. Hopefully, they'll prioritize it, and get that fixed soon. Please provide your Safari version here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: [Partially colored Arabic word in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155849/partially-colored-arabic-word-in-html)

Added zero-width character at the end helps: `<span>ش&zwj;</span><span>س</span>`