# Select part of the text like we select with a mouse using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select a part of the text similar to selecting it with a mouse.

I referred to this example here: [How to select part of a text using select method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249307/how-to-select-part-of-a-text-using-select-method).

by using this code I'm able to select all content in the element (by providing the element id). however, I am unable to select only the desired part.

with the following code, I'm able to select all the contents.

```js
var selection = window.getSelection();
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("xyz");
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(txt);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

i want to modify the code in such a way that by providing a kewyword and element id I want to slect all the instance of the keyword in that element id.

further, I want to use a loop function to loop through all the instance of the keyword and modify the text. ex: get a substring from the text etc.

Comment: So if the element in question is `<p>One Two One Two Three</p>`, and you want `One`, it'll return `OneOneOne`?

Comment: are you trying to implement find & replace functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **getElementsByClassName** you get **HTMLCollection** - all elements with the specified class name. Use loop to go through all this elements. You have possibility to get access to the element text using **innerText property**.

- find all elements with class 'post-text' on this page:

> `let elementsCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("post-text");`

- go through all html elements in the collection and replace the keyword with your own string. Note that the replace() method searches a string for the value (regular expression) and than returns a new string where the values are already replaced. If you want to replase all values in the test use the global (g) modifier.

  > ```
  > let keyWord = 'element';
  > let newValue = 'editedElementTest';
  > for (i = 0; i < elementsCollection.length; i++) {
  >      let elementText =  elementsCollection[i].innerText;
  >      let reg = new RegExp(keyWord, "g");
  >      let newStringResult = elementText.replace(reg, newValue);
  >      document.getElementsByClassName("post-text")[i].innerText = newStringResult;
  > }
  > ```